# Question editor unavailable under iPad

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor, ipad

When posting a question using an iPad, the richtext box icons are missing.

P.s.: Also the similar questions div can't be scrolled, but this has been noted earlier.

Comment: Just FYI, similar questions div *can* be scrolled by using two fingers.

Comment: Heh, if only you could run userscripts in mobile safari...

Comment: @waiwai933 good tip!

Comment: Well are we expecting a more usable text editor component for iOS usage? The current one is pretty much useless for long questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design; we disable the WMD editor on iPhone and iPad because it behaves poorly there.

Comment: Any idea why?  Does it take too much memory, or do those devices have a poor java-script implementation?

Comment: Msdn reference pages also fail to work properly on both iphone and ipad. I thought they were properly webkit based so should be more or less free of weirdeness

Comment: Why does it behave poorly? Any chance this will be fixed? The iPad is a useful device to browse stackoverflow.

Comment: Not to say that it should be enabled, but it's a pain since there is no backtick key on the iPad keyboard; the only time I'd find myself _relying_ on the GUI buttons, they're not there!

Comment: @legu "To use [backtick], go into the mail app and in the email to/cc/bcc fields you should see the backtick in the upper left on the symbols virtual keyboard. Then just copy and paste it wherever you need it." http://stdout-dev-null.blogspot.com/2009/08/backtick-grave-accent-iphone.html

Comment: @LeguRi there is a backtick key.  Tap and hold the apostrophe key, and a little menu of alternative characters pops up.  The backtick character is the left-most one.  I use this pretty frequently on my iPhone.

Comment: @Dave DeLong - _Really_? Please post this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @LeguRi done. :)

Comment: @Jeff if it behaves poorly you make it behave better, not remove it altogether!

Answer (score 5):

There is a backtick key, though this only showed up in recently (maybe with iOS 4?).  If you tap and hold the apostrophe key, you'll see a little menu pop up with alternate characters (for example, tapping and holding the "u" key shows: <kbd>ú</kbd>, <kbd>ù</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd>, <kbd>û</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>).  One of the alternate characters is the backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>).

Here's what it looks like on my iPhone:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Now if you can tell me how to do a right delete I may just award a bounty :)

Comment: Dang! It won't let me un-accept the other answer :'(