# No formatting bar on iphone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, iphone, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question editor crippled under iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/question-editor-crippled-under-ipad)

When asking questions using an iPhone, the bar above the body input doesn't show (the one that starts with Bold, Italic, etc)

It's quite annoying to have to remember the markup for bold/italic and links etc.

(Also there is no preview on the iphone)

Comment: No preview is by design; not sure about the toolbar buttons.

Comment: Also note that the iPhone doesn't have a backtick ... </wah>

Comment: @drac Actually, on the newest versions of iOS, you can find the backtick if you press and hold on the single apostrophe key.