# How to format question while using SO on phone

Tags: discussion, markdown, mobile-web

What is the easiest way to format question on the phone.
Most of the time I use SO on my iPhone and don't find it that easy.
Also do we have any iPhone app for SO ? I couldn't find any in the app store.

Comment: On Android ICS the backtick is hidden at `?123`, followed by pressing `=/<`, 2nd key on the first row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jeff [explains in another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/question-editor-unavailable-under-ipad/53485#53485), the WMD editor is disabled on iOS, so I suspect that there isn't a very easy way to format questions when using those devices.

There are a [few iPhone apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/iphone+app) that allow you to browse Stack Overflow a bit more conveniently on iOS, but since the API is currently read-only, none of them allow you to post content.