# Answering questions on a Mobile device with slider keyboard

Tags: feature-request, bug

Earlier, I tried answering a question using my mobile device (Gingerbread), but discovered that it wasn't possible to add code.  Both my physical and logical keyboard (Swype) lack the ` key to insert code.  Was this intentional, or is this indeed a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to backtick escapes for non-US keyboard?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard)

Comment: (Not a true duplicate, but I feel its answers would answer the same question. Also note that code blocks use 4 space indentation rather than backticks.)

Comment: Yep, we intentionally left it off your keyboard, sorry!

Comment: Or, better: [How to format question while using SO on phone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95669/how-to-format-question-while-using-so-on-phone). Also no answer yet, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Arjan:  The only problem is that my phone is an Android.  I'll add that into the question momentarily.  I also looked around and didn't see any truly satisfactory answers to my question.  The four spaces may work, but not with inline code.

Comment: I don't think the type of device matters a lot? (True, the other questions might not have good answers, but I'd say that any answer to *this* very question also applies to the other questions.)

Comment: Different devices have different soft keyboards.  I see your point and agree though; if an answer applied here, then it would apply to *most* mobile devices.

Comment: Also, the choice in your actual question has been answered by Nick ;-) As an aside: on ICS the backtick is hidden at `?123` followed by `=/<`, 2nd key on the first row...

Comment: Should have bought an iPhone...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering from a gingerbread mobile device with the swype keyboard. You can indeed insert code, just press and hold the <kbd>.</kbd> button. It'll change to a ', but if you keep holding it'll change to 4 other options, including `.

Comment: This is what I was looking for (embarrassingly enough).  Thank you.